# Adding optional parameters in SOAP call in PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap

The format of my SOAP call needs to be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/">  
<SOAP-ENV:Body>  
    <ns1:FunctionName>  
        <ns1:HostUserName>hostuser</ns1:HostUserName>  
        <ns1:HostPassword>pass</ns1:HostPassword>  
        <ns1:OwnerName>owner</ns1:OwnerName>  
        <ns1:UserName>user</ns1:UserName>  
        <ns1:OptionalParam>  
            <ns1:Parameters>  
                <ns1:Parameter Name="FirstName">First<ns1:/Parameter>  
                <ns1:Parameter Name="LastName">Last<ns1:/Parameter>  
            <ns1:/Parameters>  
        </ns1:OptionalParam>  
<ns1:/FunctionName>  
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

How do I represent this in a PHP request?
I build the request like this:

```
    $client = new SoapClient($url,array('trace' => 1)); 
    $data['HostUserName']=$this->hostname;
    $data['HostPassword']=$this->hostpassword;
    $data['OwnerName']=$this->ownername;
    $data['UserName']=$username;
    $data['FirstName']=$FirstName;
    $data['LastName']=$LastName;
    $result = $client->FunctionName($data);
```

I've tried a few combinations of building arrays, SOAPVAR and SOAPPARAM but nothing has worked. 
The target SOAP server is .NET based.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: There is no close tag for `<ns1:FunctionName>` and no open tag for `</ns1:SetUserProfile>`

Comment: thanks, I've fixed the XML but note that creating the SOAP request in PHP is the goal here.

Comment: You mention that you've tried a few combinations of building arrays: what have you tried?  `$data["OptionalParam"] = array("Parameters"=>array("FirstName":"First", "LastName":"Last"));`?  What XML do they produce?

Comment: And is there documentation for the service which you're attempting to use?

Comment: There is documentation, it only shows the format of the XML and some sample C# code which isn't that useful to me.

Comment: I tried your code sample, the server returns the error: Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object hasn't 'any' property in /path/to/calling/page.php. Is this a problem with the SOAP server?

Comment: do you solved that issue? I have the same problem. Its not possible to ignore optional params, before the first not optional one...